# Could pressure differentials be used to produce power?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, vacuum, power

There is potential energy between something like a vacuum in a container and a gas on the outside of it, or vice-versa. Could this energy be harvested in a vacuum, or close to vacuum situation like on mars, if you had access to a gas?

Comment: This is how internal combustion engines work. They just use combustion to produce high pressure on one side of the piston.

Comment: Could this be utilized with a vacuum and low pressure gas though

Comment: Could do, but it might not be practical since you'd lose your working fluid (release it into the vacuum) that you might have spent a lot of energy to transport to Mars.

Comment: Why transport it, I would assume there are gases, or chemicals that could easily be degraded into gasses somewhere on mars

Comment: Pressure differential can be used, all right, and it can be used up.   Without an inexhaustible source of pressure differential, your power production is temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many common types of engines, like internal combustion engines and [gas turbines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_turbine), and [wind turbines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_turbine), use a pressure difference to deliver power. There's no reason they wouldn't work just as well (or better) with a low (vacuum) exhaust pressure.

Answer (score 0):

No. In an ambient of 14.7 psi, it requires work to produce a vacuum, and an engine that runs on vacuum would produce no net work.

Comment: It doesn't take much work to produce a vacuum if you're on a spaceship. Just open a door.

Comment: But could you produce gas on mars to a pressure higher than ambience then use the difference to generate electricity

Comment: yes you could. Car engines on earth do this already.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be to drive a turbine, but it would consume the gas. would be easier to transport the energy in a battery rather than a heavy gas cylinder. The gas escaping may be able provide extra energy by being burnt , but may need oxygen also.